# How can I iterate through multiple rows and columns rather than one column?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, excel-2010, openpyxl

My job iterates only the first row and displays the data in one column.  I am trying to remove duplicates through `openpyxl` by iterating through all the rows, however it does not do this.  I have previously used `Java Apache` though we are required to migrate to `Python`.

```
wb2 = openpyxl.Workbook('E:/Yeep')
ws2 = wb2.active
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:/Yeep.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

values = []
for row in range(ws1.min_row, ws1.max_row):
  if ws1.cell(row=row,column=row).value in values:
    pass 
  else:
    values.append(ws1.cell(row=row,column=row).value)


directory = 'D:/Yeep.xlsx'
with open(directory, 'a') as outfile:
    for value in values:
        ws2.append([value])
        print(value)
wb2.save('D:/Duplication Complete.xlsx')
```

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Oh Sorry!!  Do you think that it was not iterating over all the rows?  Let me test that that :)

Comment: You are iterating a diagonal: ws1.cell(row=row,column=row)

Comment: I was referring to the syntax in the question, prior to the edit by coldspeed.

Comment: @gukoff That would explain a lot! Thank you :). Huh.. does openpyxl even support ['C:K'] Ranges akin to what I am used to.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Unique rows?

Comment: @gukoff  Yeap :). The data with duplicates starts at column C, finishes at K and 1 empty column at I.

Comment: Use `ws.iter_rows()` rather than your own counter.